# comparing strings in MACRO define

Tags: c, string, macros

can I do strcmp in a MACRO?
something like this for example:

```
#define TEST_WORD (word2,str,result){\
    if(!strcmp(word2,str)){\
        return result;\
    }\
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
TEST_WORD(word2,"add", FORMATION_ADD);
```

I basically want to compare word2 with a few strings, but the MACRO way doesn't seem to work. (word2 is a char* of course)

Comment: How does it not work? Is it giving errors? What is the output and the expected output?

Comment: well, first of all, in the define itself, the error sais "symbol str/word2 could not be resolved

Comment: Where is `result` supposed to be returned to?  The calling function?

Comment: result is what the calling function itself supposed to return. but it turned out my problem was putting a space where there shouldn't be one. so everything works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can. But you should take care about spaces...

```
#define TEST_WORD(word2,str,result) {\
    if(!strcmp(word2,str)){\
        return result;\
    }\
}
```

Comment: Specifically for macro functions the open bracket '(' must be immediately after the function name - no spaces allowed.

Comment: what do you mean by spaces? something is not working in the define, and I can't figure out what it is

Comment: spaces, damn, kind of dumb of me. that was the problem... thanx a lot

Comment: @littlerunaway, The space you have between `TEST_WORD` and the left paranthesis.

Comment: you should put `do` `while (0)` around the outer `{}`, such that the macro when expanded behaves syntactically like a statement.

Comment: @JensGustedt: This statement doesn't seem to you to be enough statement? Since there are no local variables defined, I'd rather advise to remove the outer curly brackets... Adding some impossible condition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @V-X, no it isn't. It behaves differently if you put it under an `if`, e.g. `if (a) if (b) TESTWORD(x,y); else toto();` will do something different than you might expect.

Comment: Fortunately, that will not compile... 
I'm completely shocked, that someone use this... I also found that in linux sourcecodes and also windows MFC, winsock and other libraries... that's weird... (Thank god that I don't have to do this because this way of code is forbidden by coding standards in our company)